# Conditional Formatting in cell based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, conditional-formatting

i am trying  below  formula to get value of column B all cells ,before hyphen and want to check if before hyphen character len is 8 make it green else red but not working as expected

i am using conditional formatting in ribbon and putting formula in rules

below is example of cell value in Column B

```
12345678 - XXXXXXX XXX CCC this should be green 
1234567 - XXXXXXX XXX CCC  this should be red 


Len(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))=8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a space between the 8 and the hyphen? Always, sometimes, never?

That would throw off your formula.

More generally, I think you have overcomplicated this by using LEN. Your FIND already shows the position of the hyphen from the start of the string, which indicates the length of the text/number before it.
So something like

```
=FIND("-",B2)=9
```

would show the number before the hyphen has 8 characters (use 10 instead of 9 if spaces exist).

Are other lengths possible apart from 7 or 8? Consider making everything green and only needing a rule for red, or the other way round (if you are talking about font colour; if fill colour don't add a fill to cells with no data).

Comment: yes there is space so i consider 10 , one more thing how this formula should be consider for all cell value for column B starting from row 6 as till row 5 i have my headers

Comment: When you do conditional formatting, select the range that it will apply to, and then write the formula as it would be from the first cell in that range (regardless of where the active cell is). So you would use =FIND("-",B6)=10. 
(you could actually look for " -" (space hyphen) and go back to using 9)